# Create a GROUP BY query to show the latest row

Tags: mysqli, group-concat

So my tables are: 
`user_msgs`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d6a9 
`token_msgs`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac0f

There are only these 4 users as listed. When a user sends a message to another user, the query checks if there is a communication between those 2 users already started by checking the `token_msgs` table's from_id and to_id and if no token exists, create `token` and use that in the `user_msgs` table. So the token is a unique field in these 2 tables.

Now, I want to list the users with whom `user1` has started the conversation. So if `from_id` or `to_id` include `1` those conversation should be listed.

There are multiple rows for conversations in the `user_msgs` table for same users.

I think I need to use `group_concat` but not sure. I am trying to build the query to do the same and show the latest of the conversation on the top, hence `ORDER BY time DESC`:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM user_msgs ORDER BY time DESC) as temp_messages GROUP BY token
```

Please help in building the query.

[image]

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `token_msgs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `token_msgs`
--

INSERT INTO `token_msgs` (`id`, `from_id`, `to_id`, `token`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, '1omcda84om2'),
(2, 1, 3, '1omd0666om3'),
(3, 4, 1, '4om6713bom1'),
(4, 3, 4, '3om0e1abom4');


---


CREATE TABLE `user_msgs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_msgs`
--

INSERT INTO `user_msgs` (`id`, `token`, `from_id`, `to_id`, `message`, `time`) VALUES
(1, '1omcda84om2', 1, 2, '1 => 2\r\nCan I have your picture so I can show Santa what I want for Christmas?', '2016-08-14 22:50:34'),
(2, '1omcda84om2', 2, 1, 'Makeup tip: You\'re not in the circus.\r\n2=>1', '2016-08-14 22:51:26'),
(3, '1omd0666om3', 1, 3, 'Behind every fat woman there is a beautiful woman. No seriously, your in the way. 1=>3', '2016-08-14 22:52:08'),
(4, '1omd0666om3', 3, 1, 'Me: Siri, why am I alone? Siri: *opens front facing camera*', '2016-08-14 22:53:24'),
(5, '1omcda84om2', 1, 2, 'I know milk does a body good, but damn girl, how much have you been drinking? 1 => 2', '2016-08-14 22:54:36'),
(6, '4om6713bom1', 4, 1, 'Hi, Im interested in your profile. Please send your contact number and I will call you.', '2016-08-15 00:18:11'),
(7, '3om0e1abom4', 3, 4, 'Girl you\'re like a car accident, cause I just can\'t look away. 3=>4', '2016-08-15 00:42:57'),
(8, '3om0e1abom4', 3, 4, 'Hola!! \r\n3=>4', '2016-08-15 00:43:34'),
(9, '1omd0666om3', 3, 1, 'Sometext from 3=>1', '2016-08-15 13:53:54'),
(10, '3om0e1abom4', 3, 4, 'More from 3->4', '2016-08-15 13:54:46');
```

Comment: Put DDL/DML in question itself. Do not link to external websites

Comment: Please update the question with expected result as text and also tag relevant RDBMS (not both SQLServer and MYSQL),if you want your query to work on both versions,please specify that

Comment: @TheGameiswar done

Comment: why do you use external table? I think it could be done without it too

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili .. I am not sure, I am happy to do it without an external table too. Please help me with the query to show the conversations.

Comment: I've posted answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this (on [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d6a9/7)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM user_msgs
  WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1
  ORDER BY id DESC
) main
GROUP BY from_id + to_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Thing to mention `GROUP BY from_id + to_id` this is because sum makes it unique for each conversation between two persons: like from 1 to 3 is same as from 3 to 1. No need for extra table, and it makes it harder to maintain

**UPDATE:**

Because sometimes `GROUP`ing works weird in MySQL I've created new approach to this problem:

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM user_msgs a 
LEFT JOIN user_msgs b 
    ON ((b.`from_id` = a.`from_id` AND b.`to_id` = a.`to_id`) 
      OR (b.`from_id` = a.`to_id` AND b.`to_id` = a.`from_id`)) 
    AND a.`id` < b.`id` 
WHERE (a.from_id = 1 OR a.to_id = 1) 
  AND b.`id` IS NULL 
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: Its working in the fiddle but not locally. Im tring in the console of phpMyAdmin and with php too .. what could be the issue? Please help. The one working in the fiddle is exactly what I want. http://imgur.com/a/7gWQQ  What am i doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Looking at my results its clear that its picking up the very first conversation between the 2 users and with your query its picking up the last, what is i want.

Comment: is your data big? do you have indexes? what's the error?

Comment: I use id for ordering because I think it should be faster than ordering by time. I think you will not modify time for sent messages also, thus it can be ordered by id, as it's increasing time after time

Comment: My data is whats in the fiddle. I am not getting any error. Ordering by id in the inner SQL works `select * from user_msgs
  where from_id = 1 or to_id = 1
  order by id desc` But with the same query doest work with phpMyAdmin or with PHP .. its very weird. Please help. I am close to the solution cause of your query but its just not working with actual installation of mysql. thanks

Comment: is it remote? can I see it? It's really weird, I dont understand, but, can you clean databases and backup from this fiddle data?

Comment: I created a new table called `user_msgsnew` and ran the query. Its still doing the same. :(  What could be the issue? Its somehow picking only the fist conversation between the users. Is there any other way to sort to pick the last conversation? Please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120972/discussion-between-somename-and-george-garchagudashvili).